# Android Calendar View of DatePicker

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I am using a date picker to which i set the current date. when the view in opened in a nexus 7, along with date spinner we can see a calendar. the date spinner is properly set to today as i made it to be but the calendar view is displaying 2100 year.

```
DatePickerDialog tempDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, cur_year, cur_month, cur_day);
tempDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(today.getTimeInMillis());
```

[image: as you see date spinner is proper, but calendar view is on year 2100 november]

Comment: Edit Question with you Calender code

Comment: That's all i have written, rest part is that i do show(). i get minimum date set for spinner but calendar goes to 2100.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: nope, i had to hide the calendar part and move on.

Answer (score 0):

to Initiate use init for the calender dailog.

```
        final Calendar calendarRange = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int maxYear = calendarRange.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int maxMonth = calendarRange.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int maxDay = calendarRange.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        tempDialog.init(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay,
                new OnDateChangedListener() {

                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int month, int day) {
                        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        newDate.set(year, month, day);

                        if (calendarRange.before(newDate)) {
                            view.init(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay, this);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Then Use this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int maxYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int maxMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int maxDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dialog =
    new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, maxYear , maxMonth , maxDay);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: there is no init() for DatePickerDialog